# Record creation fails in a screen flow with "invalid record type id" error, but succeeds in debug mode, why?

Tags: record-type, screen-flow, flow-builder

I have a screen flow that I'm trying to build to copy a custom object (through a quick action) and specify some slightly different values to the new one.

The flow runs fine in the Flow Builder's interface, but when enabled on the actual record, it fails with the underlying error:

> "Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: ."

I wonder why, since the running user does have access to the record type and has all the permissions necessary to create the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the input variable you are using to pass on the original record's id. Salesforce is case sensitive in this situation so, if you use `RecordId` as the API name, it won't work. It should be `recordId` instead.